# Нужна ли запятая? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

*... — поцеловав нежно в лоб Сашу(,) высказал Женя, а затем ушел на кухню.*

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, запятая нужна, поскольку она завершает деепричастный оборот.

P. S. Вот только "высказал" здесь ни к селу ни к городу. Высказать можно что-то, можно высказаться, но нельзя высказать неизвестно что.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую исправить порядок слов автора и форму слова со значением речи: ***...нежно поцеловав Сашу в лоб, сказал...***

Деепричастный оборот требует выделения, поэтому запятая необходима.

Согласна с Артёмом Луговым: в данном контексте слово "высказал" не совсем корректно, оно воспринимается негативно окрашенным. Вряд ли можно что-то  "высказать", нежно целуя в лоб. Лучше употребить нейтральное "сказал".

Answer (score 1):

Если это школьное сочинение, то, поставив запятую и заменив *высказал* на *сказал*, можно успокоиться, но если это предназначено для опубликования в том или ином виде, то надо бы подумать, как по-другому выразить "а затем ушел на кухню". В этой фразе ударение падает на слово *Женя*, а затем идет следующее действие. Это плохо воспринимается. Ср.: *Женя произнес эти слова, а затем ушел на кухню.*